# Is there any phpDocumentor 2 printable output?

Tags: phpdoc

Is there any quick way to output printable documentation using phpDocumentor 2?

Option -o doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to create a custom template (based on XSLT or Twig) that transforms the compiled class info into printable HTML. Have a look at the existing templates in the [PHPDocumentor 2 repositories](https://github.com/phpDocumentor) to get an idea what a template looks like. You can cut out much of the unneeded navigation stuff.